# Input text file - swapping integers

Tags: vb.net, string

I've a text file of integer data i.e.,

> 00201305170013333
>   01201305170013333
>   02201305170013333

I want to swap the 2nd and 3rd location of each line with its 6th and 7th index on each line. I applied the swap technique but somehow the new string is not getting updated.

Look at the code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("input.txt")
        Dim sLine As String = ""
        Dim arrText As New ArrayList()
        Do
            sLine = reader.ReadLine()
            If Not sLine Is Nothing Then
                arrText.Add(sLine)
            End If
        Loop Until sLine Is Nothing
        reader.Close()
        Dim varReplace As Integer
        Dim arrTextToString(arrText.Count) As String
        For varReplace = 0 To arrText.Count - 1
            arrTextToString(varReplace) = arrText(varReplace).ToString()
        Next

                Dim rep As Integer
                For rep = 0 To arrText.Count - 1
                    Dim two, three, mix1, mix2, six, seven As String
                    Dim str = arrText(rep)
                    two = (str(2))
                    three = (str(3))
                    six = (str(6))
                    seven = (str(7))
                    mix1 = two
                    two = six
                    six = mix1
                    mix2 = three
                    three = seven
                    seven = mix2


                    str(2) = two.ToString()
                    str(3) = three.ToString()
                    str(6) = six.ToString()
                    str(7) = seven.ToString()

                    Console.Write(two)
                    Console.Write(three)
                    Console.Write(" ")
                    Console.Write(six)
                    Console.Write(seven)
                    Console.Write(" ")
                    Console.WriteLine(str)
                Next
                'For pri = 0 To arrText.Count - 1
                'Console.WriteLine(arrTextToString(pri))
                'Next


        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: If you're importing from `System`, `System.IO`, etc, then you're not working with vb6.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out why your code does not work, but i can write a simple extension method to do the swap, something like:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Public Class StringTest
    Implements ITestable

    Public Sub ExecuteTest() Implements ITestable.ExecuteTest
        Dim theString = "00201305170013333"
        Console.WriteLine("old: " & theString)

        Dim chars = theString.ToArray()
        chars.Swap(2, 6)
        chars.Swap(3, 7)
        theString = String.Concat(chars)
        Console.WriteLine("new: " & theString)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub Swap(Of T)(records As IList(Of T), idx1 As Integer, idx2 As Integer)
        Dim item1 = records.ElementAt(idx1)
        records(idx1) = records.ElementAt(idx2)
        records(idx2) = item1
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating a string. A string is not automatically a pointer to the original object. This is basically what you are doing.

- Loop through array of strings.
- String str = copyof array[rep].
- Perform updates on str
- End Loop

What you need to do is:

- arrText[rep] = str

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, they can't be changed. You could have noticed that by the compilation error your code produces in the line you try to change a part of a string:

```
str(2) = two.ToString()
```

results in:

> MissingMemberException: Property 'Chars' is ReadOnly.

So you have to construct new strings everytime you want to *change* a string.

---

Also, I suggest using a [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to read you data, and do the swapping using a simple [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.string.format.aspx).

**Example:**

```
Sub Main
    Dim result = From fields In ReadData("c:\your\path\input.txt")
                 Select String.Format("{0}{3}{2}{1}{4}", fields)

    For Each line in result     ' note that result is lazy '
        Console.WriteLine(line) ' Do whatever '
    Next
End Sub

Iterator Function ReadData(filename As String) As IEnumerable(Of String())
    Using parser = new TextFieldParser(filename) With { .TextFieldType = FieldType.FixedWidth }
        ' read the data in fields of a specific length '
        ' so we can later simply swap the 2nd with the 4th field '
        parser.SetFieldWidths(1, 2, 2, 2, -1)
        While Not parser.EndOfData
            Yield parser.ReadFields()
        End While
    End Using
End Function
```